# Laravel .htaccess redirect all in one (1.public 2.https 3.www→non-www)

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, vesta

1. I have laravel application where `.htaccess` is redirecting to Laravel's `/public` folder.
2. Today I've added the SSL support, and I successfully updated `.htaccess` to also redirect `http` to `https`.
3. In addition to that I need it to re-write the `www` to `non-www`. There are plenty of examples how to do it individually. But I cannot find how to do it in conjunction with the first 2 requirements. **Please help.**
   *my current htaccess:*

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# for HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
#/ end of HTTPS

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your existing **.htaccess**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, but it didn't help. 
With the above parameters, it includes /public/ in the address bar. I don't want the URL's to have /public/ in it.

Comment: Can you copy the full URL you tested?

Comment: Michael, thank you very very much. It worked!!!  
I only removed this line, and it started working as expected `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public` . Now it redirects to public, from www to non-www and to HTTPS. Amazing! Thank you!
the url is erawadee.com

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Start with www 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]


    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you Saurabh, but it's getting me into error. (getting into Centos' TESTING123).
Moreover it tries to move non-www to WWW, while I need the other way around. I need to not have www in the address bar, because my "login with google/facebook" callback url doesn't include www